# Full lazy pipeline in C#

Tags: c#, pipeline

I'm designing a handler pipeline that follows the chain-of-responsibility pattern.

A pipeline handler has the following interface:

```
public interface IPipelineHandler<TContext>
{
    Func<TContext, Task> Next { get; set; }
    Task HandleAsync(TContext context);
}
```

Each handler has a reference to the next handler in the pipeline. The following class is used to build the pipeline:

```
public class PipelineBuilder<TContext>
{
    private readonly List<IPipelineHandler<TContext>> handlers
        = new List<IPipelineHandler<TContext>>();

    public PipelineBuilder<TContext> Register(IPipelineHandler<TContext> handler)
    {
        handlers.Add(handler);
        return this;
    }

    public Func<TContext, Task> Build()
    {
        IPipelineHandler<TContext> root = null;
        IPipelineHandler<TContext> prev = null;

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                root = handler;
            }
            else
            {
                prev.Next = ctx => handler.HandleAsync(ctx);
            }

            prev = handler;
        }

        return root.HandleAsync;
    }
}
```

The downside of the current implementation is that each handler in the pipeline is constructed upfront. I'd like to construct each handler on demand so instead of passing a handler instance to the build, you pass a `Func<IPipelineHandler<TContext>>`.

What modification do I need to make to `Build()` in order to work with `Func<IPipelineHandler<TContext>>` such that each pipeline handler is only created when invoked?

**In case it's not clear - each handler should be created only when it is invoked by the previous handler in the pipeline, not during the Build() method.**

Comment: You could use *DI* or *Service Locators*  and instead of passing the `IPipelineHandler` instance you could register using the concrete `Type` and then resolve the instance on-demand using that `Type`

Comment: Passing the Func isn't hard. I'm struggling with how to construct the pipeline lazily i.e. each step of the pipeline is created on demand.

Comment: I guess the composition of `DelegatingHandler`s for `HttpClient` and ASP.NET Web API server is what you would like: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientFactory.cs#L57-L89

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty simple in the end. I created a `LazyPipelineHandler` wrapper so that I could still build the pipeline but not instantiate the wrapped handler until it actually needed to be executed:

```
public class LazyPipelineHandler<TContext> : PipelineHandler<TContext>
{
    private readonly Lazy<IPipelineHandler<TContext>> innerHandler;

    public LazyPipelineHandler(Func<IPipelineHandler<TContext>> handlerFactory) 
    {
        this.innerHandler = new Lazy<IPipelineHandler<TContext>>(handlerFactory);
    }

    public override Task HandleAsync(TContext context, Func<TContext, Task> next) 
    {
        innerHandler.Value.Next = next;
        return innerHandler.Value.HandleAsync(context);
    }
}
```